# When to write 'like' insteance of just '=' is SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

in Sybase i m seen code as:

```
     select * from sys.SYSCOLUMNS where tname like 'table_name';
```

and the result is exactly the same like

```
    select * from sys.SYSCOLUMNS where tname = 'table_name';
```

why are they writing "like" instance of "="

I know that we can use like with the % to check patterns as:

```
select * from table_name where column_name like 'temp%';
```

but i dont see the sense of doing  that when is not pattern matching.

Does anyone can explain why are they doing that ?

Comment: Can't think of a reason, except personal preference. There is no functional difference between the two statements.

Comment: Worth noting this behaviour is database specific, `SELECT 'X ' = 'X', 'X ' LIKE 'X';` are not equal in MySQL for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HoneyBadger's pointed out, in this case (static string) the 'like' and '=' are functionally the same.

If the coder rarely uses '=' then it's likely some sort of personal preference.

If the coder is using a mix of 'like' and '=', or usually uses '=', it could be something as simple as the coder originally testing with a wildcard character and/or testing for NULL (under ANSINULL=true), decided to switch to a static string for whatever reason, and simply glossed over changing 'like' to '='.  Similar explanation if they cut-n-pasted a code snippet from somewhere else, replaced a wildcard string with a static string, and glossed over changing 'like' to '='.